# Suppose that $rank(x)=\alpha, rank(y)=\beta, and \alpha \leq \beta$, prove that $rank(x \cup y)=\beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that from definition, rank(A)=⋃{(rank(x))+:x∈A} .So that for the $rank (x \cup y )$, it is equal to $sup\{rank(x),rank(y)\}$ which is $\beta$. But I have no idea about how to formally prove it.  I have checked another link:[Proving $rank(\wp(x)) = rank(x)^+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41586/proving-rank-wpx-rankx) also on rank, but still confusing. Can anybody give me some hints or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note $z\in\operatorname{rank}(A)\iff \exists t\in A\colon z\in\operatorname{rank}(t)^+$.
Thus 
$$ \begin{align}z\in\operatorname{rank}(x\cup y)&\iff \exists t\in x\cup y\colon z\in \operatorname{rank}(t)^+\\
&\iff \exists t\in x\colon z\in \operatorname{rank}(t)^+\lor \exists t\in y\colon z\in \operatorname{rank}(t)^+\\
&\iff z\in \operatorname{rank}(x)\lor z\in \operatorname{rank}(y)\\
&\iff z\in \operatorname{rank}(x)\cup \operatorname{rank}(y)\end{align}$$
In other words, rank commutes with finite union (in fact, with arbitrary union).
We conclude
$$ \operatorname{rank}(x\cup y)=\operatorname{rank}(x)\cup \operatorname{rank}(y)=\alpha\cup \beta=\beta.$$